# How to build a job with params in the job-URL?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

```
http://localhost:8080/view/view_name/job/job_name/parambuild/?IP=10.10.10.10
```

Accessing the above link, says HTTP Error 404 Not found if user has not logged in.
Any permission access to be changed from job point of view, in order to redirect to the same page eventhough user has not logged in.

```
http://localhost:8080/view/view_name/job/job_name/build?IP=10.10.10.10
```

This link can be accessed in both cases user logged-in & user not logged-in.
Here, param filed will not be auto-filled by 10.10.10.10
I need param field to be auto-filled by the value passed by URL. That can be achieved by first link.

How can i access the first link page, eventhough user has not logged-in (later it can be redirected to login page, once the build button clicked) ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to trigger a build for a non logged-in user ? sounds risky ... however i would try 2 options :

1. remove the / from the /? in your first link
2. building remotely needs to pass token (should be also enabled in the job):

   curl -X POST "http://user:pass@localhost:8080/job/JOB1/buildWithParameters?token=TK1&IP=10.10.10.10"

Comment: No, I'm not trying to trigger with non-logged-in user.It's absolutely risky. Accessing first link, lands to the http error 404 page (This scenario observed, when user has not logged in). So, what i need is "I should be able to access that page even though i haven't logged in (not to build)".